# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition and navigator.geolocation.watchPosition are not working if used in same Page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

I am using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` and `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` in same html page, i am using `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` for compass pointer and `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` for displaying the distance between 2 places. if use only `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` the distance is shown but compass do not work, is there any method to use both `getCurrentPosition and watchPosition`.

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(locationUpdate, locationUpdateFail, {
    enableHighAccuracy: false,
    maximumAge: 30000,
    timeout: 27000
  });

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        showNearPlaces(position);

      });
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: No error, i think both are intersecting each other, i used ```setTimeout``` to call watchPosition, once watchPosition is called distances are not displayed correctly. for which i used ```getCurentPosition```

Comment: Would you be able to provide us a **[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** so we can verify?

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer helps some one else,
I used only `watchPosition` and stored the latitude and longitude in `global variable`, now i dont need to use `getCurrentPosition`. 
Thanks for reviewing my question.