# Geolocation API - getCurrentPosition() does not resolve when watchPosition() is activated on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, w3c-geolocation

Is it normal that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` does not resolve on Chrome if `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` was called before.

For instance the issue can be reproduced with this:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) { console.log("watchPosition", position); }, console.error);

//this wont resolve on Chrome
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { console.log("getCurrentPosition", position); }, console.error)
```

This issue was already observed in this question: [navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition and navigator.geolocation.watchPosition are not working if used in same Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62228836/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-and-navigator-geolocation-watchposition)